# Accessing a method in another class file

Tags: c#

I know this question has been asked many times on here, but i can't seem to get it right in my code.

I have a simple class with a simple method in a file called classes.cs, code below;

```
namespace Simulator
{
class wind
{
    public int[] getWindData()
    {
        int[] strings = new int[] { 19, 255, 25 };
        return strings;
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to access the returned array from getWindData from a button on the main form1.

I've tried accessing via wind.getWindData etc but it's not working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because explaining this requires an introduction to C# and OO-programming in general. This is too broad in scope and as such should be learned through a class, tutorial or good book instead.

Comment: Something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110.aspx

Comment: Would not providing links to said introduction to OOP be better than voting to close the question?

Comment: Your questions misses a fundamental part. How do you call this method? _It doesn't work_ is really the most useless thing to say here.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that wasn't that helpful. I have since done a couple of things to my code. I've made getWindData static and i'm able to grab the data with the following: var data = wind.getWindData();

Answer (score 1):

A couple of places to check... first.. your class is not marked as **public** or **protected**.  If this class is in a different assembly, you won't be able to access it.

Also possible (judging from the declaration above), getWindData is an instance level method since it is not marked as **static**, so wind.getWindData is not correct way to invoke it since assuming from the syntax shown above, wind.getWindData assume that getWindData is a static method of the wind class.

If this is not the intention, make sure you are instantiate the wind class first like..

```
var myWind = new wind();  //Create instance of the wind class first
var windData = myWind.getWindData();  //Invoke its instance method
```

If you want getWindData to be accessible without having to instantiate the wind class, mark it as static, but of course you can't have instance level state at that point anything has to be passed into the static method.

```
public static int[] getWindData() {
  //whatever here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you calling this method like `wind.getWinddata` . Then your method should be static method like below:

`public static int[] getWindData()`